# API Authentication via JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, api, authentication

I am building a JavaScript SDK for our API. The API currently requires (2-legged) OAuth authentication. Obviously this isn't suitable for a JS SDK since the key and secret are in plain site (in the JS code).

Facebook only requires your app id when you init their JS SDK, so I would like to implement something similar (or of similar simplicity). When a developer requests a key we require their app's domain. I was thinking of detecting the IP address of the submitted domain (for example myclientapp.com has 192.168.0.0 IP). And then authenticating JavaScript requests by confirming the remote hosts IP address matches.

Is this the best/easiest way of doing this?

UPDATE: As [Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup) pointed out the remote IP will be the client and thus not match the apps URL's IP. So that's out. So to reiterate I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to enforce some form of authentication in my JavaScript sdk for my API that can't be spoofed by someone else (trying to be someone elses app).

Thanks,

Gavin

Comment: The requesting IP will be the end user not the machine serving the domain - you can't use that, sorry. Or did you mean requests for an API key? I doubt they'd come from the server either.

Comment: True, dam. Any suggestions on what I could use? from the client machine, because otherwise anyone could pretend to be anyone's app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticate the user instead.

Have the (claimed, but untrustworthy) app id passed into your `init()`, jsonp out to your domain, then either:

- Return a code valid for making API requests with, if the user is logged in* and has already authorized the app.
- Pop up a window to your site (or redirect, or whatever) to have the user login (if needed) and authorize the app.

You'll have control of the user experience during authentication, and can do some human verification of the app id (show the claimed logo, name, etc.).

This does assume that you even *have* a notion of users, like Facebook does.

<sub>*Check cookies, not all browsers accept them in response to ajax requests; but all browsers will *send* them.</sub>

Comment: Kind of what I needed. Basically jsonp out of the domain when I only have the app id as auth. Then once a user is authenticated or the api is accessed via the server with (2-legged) oauth then allow standard JSON.